# Array mesh plane modifier with rotation

Tags: modifiers

I have been using the Array modifier on a plane with a playing card texture to make a deck of cards, with and Empty as the object offset so I can make a fan out of them. However, it isn't behaving like I expect. After I set the Empty as the offset, I have to Ctrl + A and hit Scale to fix the scale, but then I basically have four small decks that rotate when I only want the cards to rotate as one deck something like this:

[removed]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your problem comes from but if you want to do that with the *Array* modifier, here is the way:

- Create your card, at the centre of the scene to make it simpler.
- In *Edit* mode shift the mesh from its origin (on the Y axis in my case).
- Back in *Object* mode, create an empty at the same point as the card origin.
- Give your card an *Array* modifier. Choose *Object Offset* with the empty as object. Choose the *Count* value you want.
- Rotate the empty on the Z axis. In my case, as I've chosen a count of 36, I have to rotate 10° so that it make a complete circle.
- As you don't want the cards to be on the same Z level, rise the empty a bit on the Z axis (use <kbd>shift</kbd> while you move to make it more precise).

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I actually found one problem I was having is I was using the Import Image as Plane add-on, and I didn't realize I needed to change and apply the rotation to make it work too. I'm new to blender, so again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial Shows you fast and simple

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9EN4SpwWqo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Instead of just giving a link briefly summarize the tut.